# SvelteKit and retrieving images from PostgreSQL via node-postgres

Tags: endpoint, node-postgres, bytea, sveltekit

Storing ~100 JPEGs (24K-100K each) in a table in PostgreSQL as a **bytea** column.
The `<img/>` tag src attributes reference the SvelteKit endpoint:

```html
<img src="/api/file/18.json" alt="Person"/>
```

Getting this error:

> Invalid response from route /api/file/76.json: Uint8Array body must be accompanied by content-type: application/octet-stream header

```js
export async function get({ params }) {
  const { id } = params
  const sql = `SELECT _id, name, type, data FROM files WHERE _id = $1;`
  const { rows } = await db.query(sql, [id])
  const file = rows[0]
  return {
    headers: {
      'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${file.name}`,
      'Content-type': file.type
    },
    body: file.data
  }
}
```

As [SvelteKit endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints) don't interact with req/res objects because they're only available on certain platforms, I can't just write out the bytea value as a stream to a response object but I'm not sure what the right approach is.

Also tried this SQL statement...

```sql
SELECT _id, name, type, encode(data, 'base64') as data FROM files WHERE _id = $1;
```

But it didn't help.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**: The problem may be related to a SvelteKit bug - see https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1438.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation in SvelteKit was resolved on June 11th. I also needed to put the file.data in a new Uint8Array...

```js
// routes/api/file/[filenum].ts

import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import { query } from '../_db'

export const get: RequestHandler = async ({ params }) => {
  const { filenum } = params
  const { rows } = await query(`SELECT * FROM find_file($1);`, [filenum])
  if (rows) {
    const file = rows[0]
    return {
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${file.name}"`,
        'Content-Type': file.type
      },
      body: new Uint8Array(file.data)
    }
  } else return {
    status: 404
  }
}
```

Here's source for the find_file() function in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.find_file(
    integer,
    OUT _id integer,
    OUT name character varying,
    OUT type character varying,
    OUT data bytea)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
SELECT _id, name, type, data FROM files WHERE _id = $1 LIMIT 1
$BODY$;
```

and the query() function...

```js
import pg from 'pg'

const pgNativePool = new pg.native.Pool({
  max: 10, // default
  connectionString: <string> import.meta.env.VITE_DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})

type QueryResponse = (sql: string, params?: Array<any>) => Promise<pg.QueryResult<any>>
export const query: QueryResponse = (sql: string, params?: Array<any>) => pgNativePool.query(sql, params)
```